# Finding Contiguous Ranges

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to find the contiguous ranges given a set of dates by day

given the following sample

```
2016-01-01
2016-01-02
2016-01-03
2016-01-04
2016-01-05
2016-01-06
2016-01-08
2016-01-09
2016-01-10
2016-01-11
2016-01-12
2016-01-15
2016-01-16
2016-01-17
2016-01-20
2016-01-21
2016-01-30
2016-01-31
2016-02-01
```

I expect the following result

```
2016-01-01-2016-01-06
2016-01-08-2016-01-12
2016-01-15-2016-01-17
2016-01-20-2016-01-21
2016-01-30-2016-01-31
2016-02-01-2016-02-01
```

I have already came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867557/finding-gaps-sequential-numbers) question which is almost the opposite of what I want but with integers.
I have formulated the following which works with integers.

```
awk 'NR==1 {l=$1; n=$1} {if ($1==n){n=$1+1} else{print l"-"n-1; l=$1 ;n=$1+1} } END {print l"-"$1}' file.txt
```

Comment: hmmm even if you do manage to do this, you still have another problem to solve, what if the month has 30 days? the last day (so the 30th) would be printed as well, as it would be thought that the next one doesnt exist in the text. also what if the month has 29 or 31 days, in order to make this work, you have to "tell" to the script which month has how many days, so that it would know  when not to print the last day of the month.

Comment: If we cross a month boundary its ok to start a new range. I have updated the example and results to reflect this. Also if the date can be transformed to an ordinal value this wouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for `mktime()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="-" }
{ currSecs = mktime( $1" "$2" "$3" 0 0 0" ) }
(currSecs - prevSecs) > (24*60*60) {
    if (NR>1) {
        print startDate, prevDate
    }
    startDate = $0
}
{ prevSecs = currSecs; prevDate = $0 }
END { print startDate, prevDate }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2016-01-01-2016-01-06
2016-01-08-2016-01-12
2016-01-15-2016-01-17
2016-01-20-2016-01-21
2016-01-30-2016-02-01
```

With any awk if you don't care about ranges restarting when months change (as apparent in your expected output and the comment under your question):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="-" }
{ currYrMth = $1 FS $2; currDay = $3 }
(currYrMth != prevYrMth) || ((currDay - prevDay) > 1) {
    if (NR>1) {
        print startDate, prevDate
    }
    startDate = $0
}
{ prevYrMth = currYrMth; prevDay = currDay; prevDate = $0 }
END { print startDate, prevDate }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2016-01-01-2016-01-06
2016-01-08-2016-01-12
2016-01-15-2016-01-17
2016-01-20-2016-01-21
2016-01-30-2016-01-31
2016-02-01-2016-02-01
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Awk you can use its [time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html).

```
gawk -F - 'NR==1 || $1 "-" $2 "-" $3 != following {
    if (following != "") print start "-" latest;
    start = $1 "-" $2 "-" $3
    this = mktime($1 " " $2 " " $3 " 0 0 0")
  }
  {
    this += 24*60*60
    following = strftime("%F", this)
    latest = $1 "-" $2 "-" $3 }
  END { if (start != latest) print start "-" latest }' filename
```

Unit ranges will print like "2016-04-15-2016-04-15" which is a bit of a wart, but easy to fix if you need to.  Also the `END` block has a bug in this case, but again, this should at least get you started.

Answer (score 0):

gawk:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
        FS="-"
}
{
        a[NR]=mktime($1" "$2" "$3" 0 0 0")
        b[NR]=$2;
        if ( (a[NR-1]+86400) != a[NR] || b[NR-1]!=b[NR] ) {
                if(NR!=1){
                        print s" - "strftime("%Y-%m-%d",a[NR-1])
                };
                s=$0
        }
}
END{
        print s" - "$0
}
```

Create array `a` with index `NR` and value as epochtime derived from $0 using awk time function `mktime`.

Array `b` with index `NR` and value as the month in `$2`
if either epoch time from last line + 86400 ( +1 day) is not equal to epoch time in current line or month in previous line and current line differs, except for first line, print value in `s" - "strftime("%Y-%m-%d",a[NR-1]` and reassign `s` which is the start date with `$0`

END:
Print the last start time `s` and last line