# awk - Issues with if else statements

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk

Let `file.txt` be the following file

```
1
2
3
5
6
7
15
16
17
19
20
23
24
```

I was trying to write an `awk` command that prints the ranges of numbers that are missing. When the range includes only one number, then this number alone should be printed. The expected output is

```
4
8-14
18
21-22
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867557/finding-gaps-sequential-numbers) pretty much did the job for me with the one liner

```
awk '$1!=p+1{print p+1"-"$1-1}{p=$1}' file.txt

4-4
8-14
18-18
21-22
```

I tried to modify it to

```
awk 'if ($1!=p+1){if (p+1!=$1-1) {print p+1"-"$1-1} else {print p+1} }{p=$1}' file.txt
```

but it does not work as expected. I seem to misunderstand the if-else grammar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the first couple of pages of the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to solve this problem. Then read the rest of the book :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk '$1 != p+1 {print p+1 ($1-1 > p+1 ? "-" $1-1 : "")} {p=$1}' file

4
8-14
18
21-22
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to check your answer (or respond to your comment). Yes it worked fine. I have already used it a lot and modified it quite a bit. Thank you! +1