# Finding gaps in csv column using AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I trying to use AWK to find gaps in sequential list of numbers in a column. I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867557/finding-gaps-sequential-numbers) which has the same requirement as mine, but couldnt get it to work.
My input is in a csv and looks similar to following.

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg
0,22,33,44,55,66,77
1,88,99,11,12,13,14
2,154,165,-22,-31,-40,-49
3,220,231,-55,-74,-93,-112
6,418,429,-154,-203,-252,-301
7,484,495,-187,-246,-305,-364
8,550,561,-220,-289,-358,-427
```

I have tried

```
awk 'NR>1 && $1!=p+1{print p+1"-"$1-1}{p=$1}' file
```

and it keeps printing even when the range exists. 
I suspected it could be due to I am starting my values from 0 not 1, did few workarounds, still could not get it to work.

I am expecting to print a warning when there is a gap, for example in this case
"missing 4-5"

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Either your description is wrong or your example is wrong as your description says your input is a CSV but your example contains no Commas. Fix your question to be accurate.

Comment: @EdMorton I have updated the question with the CSV. When I copied the data from excel, it had removed commas. My apologies

Comment: @anubhava I am expecting to print the missing range, in this case 4-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this awk command to get your output with missing number in the first column of csv file:

```
awk -F, '{while (NR>2 && $1 > p+1) print ++p; p=$1} 1' file.csv

aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg
0,22,33,44,55,66,77
1,88,99,11,12,13,14
2,154,165,-22,-31,-40,-49
3,220,231,-55,-74,-93,-112
4
5
6,418,429,-154,-203,-252,-301
7,484,495,-187,-246,-305,-364
8,550,561,-220,-289,-358,-427
```

Comment: If you want only missing value then use: `awk -F, '{while (NR>2 && $1 > p+1) print ++p; p=$1}' file.csv`

Comment: thanks a lot for help. This is exactly what I was looking for !!

Comment: my apologies. I didn't un-accept your answer. I first accepted your answer later I also accepted karakfa 's answer. The latter action "automatically" has un-accepted your answer. I am a novice to stackoverflow. Can there be only a single accepted answer for a question?

Answer (score 0):

you need a slight twist to handle both the header and the initial value (here being 0, which is not handled correctly in the referenced script)

```
$ awk 'NR==1{p=$1-1; next} $1!=p+1{print p+1"-"$1-1} {p=$1}' file

5-19
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but doesn't work for me. I have updated the question with a valid CSV. I am tried you solution

Comment: $ awk 'NR==1{p=$1-1; next} $1!=p+1{print p+1"-"$1-1} {p=$1}' summary.csv
0--1
1-0
2-1
3-2
4-5
7-6
8-7

Comment: Apologies for the multiple comments. Pressing 'enter' submits my comments. Anyway I am getting the above output when I try your solution

Comment: Well.., now that is a different input file,  You have to specify input delimiter as `-F,`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. your suggestion with -F, worked!! Thanks a lot..